# PrestaShop display set of products

Tags: prestashop

Newbie to PrestaShop (v 1.7) I need to display a set of products (filtered according to certain criteria - defined elsewhere dynamically ) in a similar way as the category products listings.  Basically, it's the same page as the category listings but a different data source. What's the best way to achieve this? override a core controller or create a controller in a module?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to create a new module with front controller to displays your filtered products